# How to change 'data' of all the values in key-value pair in JSON?

Tags: python

I have a JSON data which is:

```
json_string = '[
  {
    "degree": "masters",
    "school": "PU",
    "joinedOn": {
      "year": 2021,
      "month": "FEB"
    },
    "address": [
      {
        "b_Address": "UK",
        "city": "London"
      },
      {
        "b_Address": "US",
        "city": "Texas"
      }
    ],
    "fieldOfStudy": "MBA",
    "levelOfEducation": "MASTER",
    "currentlyStudying": "true"
  }
]'
```

I want to change the data of every keys like this:

```
   {
  "degree": "5pcBBS07",
  "school": "ZozkeyAV",
  "joinedOn": "y5cO3L9i",
  "address": "mBa3oqMs",
  "fieldOfStudy": "MBA",
  "levelOfEducation": "MASTER",
  "currentlyStudying": "true"
}
```

Here the values of `"degree", "school","phone","joinedOn","address"` has been changed. Buy my expectation was since `"joinedOn"` has an `object` but the output is coming as:

```
"joinedOn": "y5cO3L9i"
```

I want the output to be:

```
"joinedOn": {
          "year": XYZ,
          "month": "ABC"
        }
```

Same case goes for `"address"`. I am just getting single value `"mBa3oqMs"`, I want the output to be:

```
  "address": [
          {
            "b_Address": "ABC",
            "city": "DEF"
          },
          {
            "b_Address": "GHI",
            "city": "JKL"
          }
        ]
```

I tired as:

```
json_string = '[{"degree": "masters", "school": "PU", "joinedOn": {"year": 2021, "month": "FEB"}, "address": [{"b_Address": "UK", "city": "London"},{"b_Address": "US", "city": "Texas"}], "fieldOfStudy": "MBA","levelOfEducation": "MASTER","currentlyStudying": "true"}]'
        
data = load_json_data(json_string)

if data:
    fields_to_anonymize = ["degree", "school","phone","joinedOn","address"]
    anonymized_data = anonymize_json_data(data[0], fields_to_anonymize)

    # Alternatively, convert it back to a string
    anonymized_json_string = json.dumps(anonymized_data)
    print(anonymized_json_string)
```

Loading JSON file:

```
def load_json_data(json_string):
    try:
        data = json.loads(json_string)
        return data
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print("Error parsing JSON:", str(e))
        return None
```

Changing the values:

```
def anonymize_json_data(data, fields_to_anonymize):
    for field in fields_to_anonymize:
        if field in data:
            data[field] = generate_random_string()
    return data

def generate_random_string(length=8):
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters_and_digits) for _ in range(length))
```

How can I get the output where key will have object and the object will have their own changed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are ignoring the fact that some values of the dictionary can be of type `dict` or `list`

You should change your code to handle that, Check the below code with the required changes

```
def randomize(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {key: generate_random_string() for key, value in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        return [randomize(x) for x in data]
    return data

def anonymize_json_data(data, fields_to_anonymize):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, (dict, list)) and key in fields_to_anonymize:
            data[key] = randomize(value)       
        elif key in fields_to_anonymize:
            data[key] = generate_random_string() 
    return data
```

With this change you will be able to get the output in the expected format
**Output:**

```
{'degree': '85SovY6B',
 'school': 'D6YBpJDB',
 'joinedOn': {'year': 'ggbmvYEd', 'month': 'ZUoJOO6A'},
 'address': [{'b_Address': 'F6w5Qwsh', 'city': 'Xnz1pDbg'},
             {'b_Address': '1zjZ0mLw', 'city': 'ofB677lP'}],
 'fieldOfStudy': 'MBA',
 'levelOfEducation': 'MASTER',
 'currentlyStudying': 'true'}
```